# Как лучше осуществить апдейт базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql

На примере интернет-магазина. Если в админке зайти в раздел Товаров то возле каждого товара из списка будет `checkbox`. Выбираем 70 товаров из 100 и нажимаем `Скрыть товар` чтоб он не отображался на сайте.

По идее это 70 запросов. К примеру в ячейку `visible` заменить `1` на `0` с каждым из 70 id.

```
UPDATE product SET visible=0 WHERE id=1
UPDATE product SET visible=0 WHERE id=2
UPDATE product SET visible=0 WHERE id=3
```

и так далее до `id=70`...

И да, я знаю что так никто не делает, точнее я почти уверен) Так как это делается чтоб не создавать чудовищную такую нагрузку на бд?

Была у меня еще **идея** все `id` которые к примеру не должны отображаться на сайте, запись в одну ячейку через запитаю или точку, а потом с помощью `explode` разбирать строку, но это мне кажется еще безумнее.

Ну и идея #3, создать такой один большущий запрос на апдейт, но не будет ли он слишком уж велик?

*PS надеюсь понятно расписал*

Comment: максимум что приходит в голову собрать implode список id и дать `update product set visible=0 where id in(1,2,3,...)`

Comment: @Mike, запрос с такой конструкцией никогда еще не использовал, виглядит очень просто, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от условий. Если ID не по порядку, а судя по тому что пользовательский ввод идет, то не по порядку, тогда так:

```
UPDATE product SET visible = 0 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4...);
```

Насчет лимита на кол-во параметров в `IN()` можно не беспокоется. По умолчанию равен `4194304` и задается через настройку [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) судя по [мануалу](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). Я в своей жизни видел ну оооочень длинные запросы с тысячами ID.

Собрать такой запрос в php не проблема – либо через [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) либо через [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать

```
UPDATE product SET visible=0 WHERE id<70
```

Answer (score 0):

Если id идёт подряд без пропусков, то используйте `between`:

```
UPDATE product
SET visible=0
WHERE id between 0 and 70
```

Или простое неравенство:

```
UPDATE product
SET visible=0
WHERE id >= 0 and id <= 70
```

Comment: думал об этом, но ид не идут подряд, есть еще варианты?)